# Multinomial identity - guidance needed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I need hints on a direction to prove that 
 $$\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n} {{k+1\choose2}\choose k} ={{n+1\choose2}\choose1,2,3.....,n}$$ 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: every multinomial coefficient is a product of binomial coefficients similar to this one. For example,
$$\binom{3n-3}{n,n-1,n-2}=\binom{3n-3}{n} \binom{2n-3}{n-1} \binom{n-2}{n-2}$$